# Change the group.id of spring-kafka listeners without re-processing processed or losing unprocessed messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have few **`Kafka listeners`** consuming from different `topics` but they are under a same consumer group - `group-1`. (legacy-code.)

As it's not a good practice to keep the listeners consuming from different topics in the same group.

We want to separate the consumer groups for each listener, i.e. listener consuming from `topic-1` would be in a separate group than the listener consuming from `topic-2`.

As per the docs, we could mention the `groupId` property over each `@KafkaListener`, but what we are afraid of is:-

1. If we set the `auto.offset.reset` for new consumer groups as
   `latest`, then we will be losing on some messages, as when our old
   common consumer group dies, due to consumer `LAG` some messages must not have been processed by it, and the new consumer group will not be processing those messages and just starts reading from the latest offset.
2. If we set the `auto.offset.reset` for new consumer groups as
   `earliest`, then we will be processing the same messages again, as new consumers starts reading from the topic's earliest offset present on broker.

> We want to eliminate both the above cases. Is there a way to do this
> safely in spring-kafka.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, I have come across this scenario more times than I think I would. This is how I went about it

1. Use console-consumer with `--group new-CG-name`, `--from-beginning` and `--max-messages 1` so that it consumes just one message and the consumer group is registered with the broker/zookeeper
2. Stop the current consumer app and find out the offset for each of the partition for the given topic-current consumer group
3. Using consumer-group.sh, Change the new-CG-name's offset for all of the partitions to the same number as the current CG's offset
4. Change the consumer group name in your listener app to new name and start the app

Step 1 may not be necessary. You can experiment without it

Comment: You can also do it programmatically (assuming all current consumers are stopped); create a `KafkaConsumer` with the old group (don't subscribe or assign any partitions). Call `committed()` to get the current committed offsets. Create another consumer with the new group and perform `seek()` operations.

Comment: You can use consumer with seek option. can store the last processed offset for a consumer group to a journal store(which is accessible to all the consumers of a group) and in case of restart they can seek from last offset, check the documentation [here][1]


  [1]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek

Answer (score 1):

You can use consumer with seek option. can store the last processed offset for a consumer group to a journal store(which is accessible to all the consumers of a group) and in case of restart they can seek from last offset, check the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek)